# Need help with wires - Replacing bedroom light fixture with ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, bedroom

[image]

Hello, first time here and I'm in need of some help. I am trying to replace my simple light fixture in my bedroom with a ceiling fan.
First thing I want to do is take off the original ceiling box and install one that is rated for fans. I was able to install a new light fixture in the kitchen with ease, only 1 set of black, red, and copper wires. However, the bedroom has 2 sets coming from both directions of the box with everything twisted together (black-black, white-white, single red, and copper-copper with a nut grounded to the box). The original light fixture only had 2 wires, black and white. The black wire was connected to the red, and the white wire was joined with the other 2 whites. The black-black and copper were not used?
Am I suppposed to untwist and separate all the wires, knock the box out, then reconnect them again the same way? Why are there 2 sets of wires like this? The bare copper is twisted on pretty hard and tight.

Thanks everyone[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box for this light?

Comment: Is that box *rated* for a ceiling fan?  I would expect to see that stamped in the box or the usual accoutrement one finds in a fan box. The reason that matters is both weight and ***vibration***, the combination will tear a normal box out of the ceiling.

Comment: I can't tell if it is or not, that's why I wanted to knock it out and put in a box that I know for sure is rated for a fan. I just never saw 2 sets of wires like this before.

Answer (score 0):

It's a switch loop with neutral. If you look behind the switch you will see a white/black/red cable, with white capped off and red and black through the switch. The white/black in the ceiling blox comes from the breaker and will be unswitched hot.

So yeah reconnect everything the same way it was, black going through, red to the new fixture and branching off the white and copper to the neutral and ground connections resp.

However it may be that the existing ceiling box is adequate for the fan already.

Comment: I will check behind the switch tomorrow morning. How do I know if it is already adequate for a fan? It seems pretty loose, connected to only one side. I can push/pull pretty easily.

Comment: Look inside the box  if it is fan rated it will be stamped inside box. Looks like it is not.Before you rip  box out ,Can you get above it to take out attic ect.  There are many ways to get box out with out damage to ceiling.Get back to us on that.   The wires look like they have to go that way  label good take pics

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have access to get above it. The box moves pretty easily, I'm not sure if it can support the force of a fan. I don't see any stamps either. That's why I wanted to put in a ceiling box with a bar hanger to be safe. What other methods are there to get the old box out besides knocking it upwards?

Comment: So I just wanted to make sure again, I'm supposed to connect the new fan's black and blue wires to my red wire and reconnect the 2 original black wires together as it was before? White-white, and green-bare copper? So the two original blacks are still unused? Just wanted to double check because the instructions say black/blue to the ceiling's black

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the blacks are hot in and down to switch and red is the switch leg back for light and fan or they could have used a white as a switch leg or to feed the switch hot and then you would have 2 switch legs there already. One for light and one for fan. Checking in the switch box as mentioned will be sure way to tell.